# Should I upgrade to Intellij Ultimate Edition?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am working in java and primarily Scala.  I'm using the community edition of Intellij.  I'm curious if its worth it to upgrade to the Ultimate Edition?
I've been back and forth with Intellij and Eclipse... and for Scala dev I like Intellij a little bit better (for now).

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9):

The best way to find it is to try, Jetbrains give a [30-day trial](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for the Ultimate edition.

But it does not seem to have [specific features](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) for Scala in the Ultimate edition.

Comment: The Scala support in CE and UE are identical. If you like feature comparison matrixes, they have one: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Thank you... I have looked through the features list.  I guess for me its the little things in an IDE that make slingin code easier and was curious if anybody had any feedback on things that didn't make the marketing list

Comment: The Play Framework is supported only in the Ultimate edition, not in the Community edition.

Answer (score 5):

Because I already did the upgrade, I would say simply Yes: it's worth every invested penny.
Of course, you need to give the trial version a chance and see for yourself, always.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth the money. If you do some web programming or use Spring the Ultimate Edition has really good support for it. Not mentioning they take reported bugs seriously.

See the f[eature comparison for yourself](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Answer (score 1):

My employer paid for my upgrade. I definitely appreciate the Ultimate Edition - I make constant use of the Spring functionality.

Also - the UML diagrams are really handy to be able to just pull up instantly with a keystroke combination.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was well worth it myself. If you're being paid to program, I actually see zero reason to stay with the community edition at all.